# Кастомные причины для закрытия вопросов

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, причины-закрытия

Пожалуйста, перетащите с большого Stack Overflow причины для закрытия вопросов, которые отображаются при выборе пункта **не по теме, потому что…**:

- Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
- Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Или в переводе с басурманского:

- Вопросы с просьбами **предоставить рекомендации или найти книги, инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие внешние ресурсы** являются на Stack Overflow оффтопиком, так как приводят к спорам и спаму. Вместо этого опишите проблему и что вы сделали для её решения.
- Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой ("**почему этот код не работает?**") должны включать желаемое повдение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до отправки вопроса.

(Исключил первые две причины про **Super User** и **Server Fault**: я так и не понял, какая официальная позиция относительно вопросов по данным тематикам.)

Также очень важно перевести страницу из справки [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Это поможет бороться с юзерами, которые вываливают тонны кода (или вообще ссылки на сайт) с припиской "исправьте".