# Обсуждение раздела справки "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"

Tags: обсуждение, справка, тематика

Пожалуйста, предложите ваше содержимое разделу ["На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) для сайта [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Stack Overflow на русском** - это сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов.

#### Какие вопросы можно задавать?

Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:

- к конкретной задаче программирования - коду, алгоритмам, реализации
  алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
- к инструментам для разработки - языки программирования, среды,
  операционные системы, пакеты программ, фреймворки, библиотеки;
- к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;
- к настройке физических, виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений,
  серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их настройки,
  мониторинга и автоматизации процессов;
- к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой
  можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для
  разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального
  администрирования IT систем.

#### Но перед этим:

Прежде чем задать вопрос...

- Сначала убедитесь, что
  [такой вопрос не задавался ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Воспользуйтесь
  вашим любимым поисковиком и/или
  [встроенным поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search), и по
  другим ключевым словам тоже, и даже на второй странице выдачи.
- Представьте, что вы знаете ответ на свой вопрос, оцените не
  потребуется ли для ответа написать небольшую книгу. Возможно
  кто-нибудь ее и напишет, но не в рамках ответа на этот конкретный
  вопрос.
- Если вы и правда знаете ответ,
  [поделитесь им с сообществом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer),
  другие участники будут благодарны вам и наверняка найдутся те, кто
  сможет предложить лучшее решение, быть может, основываясь на вашем.
- Постарайтесь *проиллюстрировать свой вопрос небольшим фрагментом
  кода*, иногда код скажет больше, чем ваше объяснение. Но не
  увлекайтесь, формулировка вопроса также должна присутствовать,
  притом как можно более кратко и четко.
- Постарайтесь правильно подобрать
  [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags) для вопроса. Для наиболее
  популярных меток есть описания, для каких вопросов они
  используются.
- Обязательно прочтите в справке о том,
  [как задавать хорошие вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  и
  [какие вопросы задавать не стоит вовсе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Активные участники с высокой репутацией, а модераторы их скорее всего
поддержат, могут
[закрыть или заморозить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) ваш вопрос, если им покажется, что он уже задавался или на него
сложно дать однозначный притом краткий (не больше нескольких абзацев)
ответ или ответы будут по большей части зависеть от мнения отвечающих.

#### Вопросы по теме, но которые не стоит задавать:

Формат сайта подразумевает общение в виде вопросов и ответов на них и,
хотя программисты любят поговорить о чем угодно, все-таки некоторые
вопросы не приветствуются даже если они и принадлежат указанной выше
тематике.

- Поиск ошибок в коде. Прежде чем спрашивать "почему у меня не
  работает вот этот (простыня из тысячи строк) код?" постарайтесь
  сами локализовать проблему, выделить минимальный фрагмент кода, на
  котором, как вы считаете возникает проблема. Прочитайте о том,
  [как создать минимальный, но самодостаточный пример, демонстрирующий проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести. "У меня программа не
  работает, хотя вот тут такой же код работает нормально". Прежде чем
  задавать вопрос, убедитесь на
  [минимальном примере](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), что
  проблема не в банальной опечатке.
- Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник
  вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте
  конкретный вопрос в чем заключается проблема, которую вы не можете
  решить. Программирование - это то, в чем надо разбираться самому,
  либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование - лишний
  предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах,
  выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь
  предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот - моветон.
- Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по
  программированию и администрированию. Такие вопросы задаются
  довольно часто (и удаляются). Тем временем есть
  [несколько вопросов по компьютерной литературе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8), где содержатся
  довольно большие списки различных изданий. Также список литературы
  часто можно найти в описаниях меток по соответствующим темам.
- Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если
  они не уникальны к программированию.

#### Мета-вопросы

Если у вас есть вопросы, относящиеся к работе сайта, по поводу
[модерирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators), вы
не знаете как правильно задать вопрос, у вас есть предложение по
улучшению сайта, вы нашли ошибку в переводе движка на русский язык,
смело задавайте вопрос на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/),
специально предназначенной для таких тем. Также всегда можно
пообщаться с активными участниками сообщества в
[чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: Это должна быть **краткая содеражтельная** статья, которая предназначена для тех, кто **любит читать правила**. Исходя из первого, лирическое отступление про программистов — избыточно (я уж не говорю о том, что оно напичкано какими-то дикими стереотипами). Исходя из второго, повторять про поиск десять раз — хамство (человек уже залез в справку и внимательно изучает тексты — это другая аудитория; потребители фастфуда в лучшем случае "тур" осилят, и то вопрос).

Comment: 1. Объядинять всеобъемлющие вопросы и самостоятельные ответы в один пункт — это плохая идея. Если человек ответил сам, это не делает вопрос менее всеобъемлющим. Такие вопросы всё равно серьёзно рискуют быть закрытыми. 2. Информация про метки избыточна. Инструкция отобразится при создании вопроса. Это НЕ инструкция по использованию сайта, это статья про онтопик. 3. Я не понял пассаж "Не волнуйтесь, если в приведенном вами фрагменте ошибок не будет".

Comment: Вообще, мне нравится, что статья написана по-человечески. Что меня смущает — это что она стилистически будет выделяться на фоне остальных. Я бы предпочёл что-то чуть более нейтральное, чтобы читающему справку не разорвало мозг от переключения стиля. Ну или вам придётся и все остальные статьи на сайте переводить. Только их мно-о-ого. :)

Comment: @Athari, спасибо за фидбэк. убрал-причесал-учел. Про метки не согласен, пока оставил. Если сообщество не против, то предлагаю этот ответ редактировать совместно. Либо предлагайте исправленные варианты в отдельных ответах, плагиат разрешается и приветствуется, тем более ответы все равно общие.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: Может быть, стоит выделить подзаголовки, чтобы не выглядело сплошной стеной текста. Например, отделить жирным заголовком список вопросов не по теме.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: у меня есть пара предложений, можно этот ответ в гитхаб выложить, чтобы пару PR послать и отдельно их обсудить (и поправить если необходимо)? Отдельные ответ нужен только, если консенсуса не будет.

Comment: @VladD, да, стоило бы. Но что-то не могу придумать подзаголовки...

Comment: @jfs, я думаю, что прямо по месту можно здесь редактировать, в случае чего можно откатить. Обсудить и в чате можно если будет что.

Comment: Добавил разбивку на темы (жирные заголовки частей).

Comment: @VladD: часть: "какие вопросы не стоит задавать" на другой странице справки должна находится [/help/dont-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). В данном ответе должно быть содержимое только для [/help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). То есть эту часть можно озаглавить: "Некоторые вопросы не стоит задавать, даже если они принадлежат разрешённым тематикам:"

Comment: @jfs: Логично. Сейчас поправлю...

Comment: @VladD: я уже поправил.

Comment: @jfs: Кажется, не успел :-)

Answer (score 5):

Не соглашусь с полной калькой перевода большого SO.

В Хэшкод был неудачный опыт попытки разделения собственно программирования и околопрограммирования - был выделен отдельный форум по вопросам околопрограммирования (администрирования и проч.), но форум не выжил. Большой SO он большой и он может себе позволить точное разделение тематик. Маленький SO (то бишь по старому Хэшкод) - не может себе этого позволить (по крайней мере пока), так что я за то чтобы выключить из потенциальных оффтопиков темы относящиеся к околопрограммированию: обучение, поиск информации, работа, интервью и администрирование. Потом когда нибудь в сверкающем будущем можно будет разделить русский SO на несколько субфорумов.

Answer (score 3):

[ru.so] - это форум, посвященный программированию. И если ваш вопрос относится

- к конкретной задаче программирования (алгоритмы, код, ...);
- к конкретным инструментам программирования (языки, среды, ...) (операционные системы, пакеты программ, ...);
- к чему-нибудь касающемуся исключительно программирования;
- к настройке серверов, рабочих станций и их администрированию;
- к работе сетей;

то [ru.so] - это удачное место, чтобы задать ваш вопрос.

Поскольку труд программиста зачастую выражается в написании текста: программы или скрипта, будет уместно, если вы приведете необходимую часть кода.

Используйте поиск, чтобы найти ответ на интересующий вас вопрос. В современных обозревателях, чтобы быстрее набирать запросы, можно задействовать горячие клавиши: Tab - чтобы попасть в строку ввода, Enter - чтобы отправить запрос.

Вы всегда можете задать вопрос и ответить на него сами, если вы чувствуете, что знание, которым вы хотите поделиться, будет полезно другим. Это равносильно публикации статьи в блоге, оформленной как вопрос и ответ.

Comment: копипаст с Хэшкода.

Answer (score 2):

Так как SO на русском — это как SO на английском, только по-русски, то не вижу причин слишком далеко уходить от статьи, которую на протяжении долгого времени шлифовали на большом SO. Предлагаю свой перевод.

Текст можно подшлифовать и при желании перетащить [критерии для онтопика ещё и из Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) и/или [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), раз уж тематику решили сделать шире. Просто выпилить запреты на оффтопик нельзя, потому что на SF и SU тоже есть свои строгие критерии. Вводить строгии критерии для вопросов по программированию, но оставлять критерии для вопросов по ПО на личное усмотрение будет ошибкой.

Часть текста позаимствована из [перевода причин для закрытия вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2) (которые я всё-таки надеюсь увидеть в диалоге закрытия вопросов). В оригинальной статье тоже копипаста из причин закрытия вопросов (всё, кроме причины про домашние задания — её подло выпилили из диалога).

Ещё архиважно перевести статью MCVE/SSCCE. На неё ссылки отовсюду.

---

### На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?

Stack Overflow — сайт для профессиональных программистов и программистов-любителей, тех, кто пишет код, потому что любит писать код. Нам кажется, что [лучшие вопросы на Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) содержат хоть немного кода, но если вопрос по одной из следующих тем:

- конкретная проблема, связанная с программированием,
- алгоритм,
- приложения, обычно используемые программистами,
- практическая, решаемая задача, относящаяся к разработке приложений,

...то Stack Overflow — удачное место, чтобы задать вопрос!

Пожалуйста, [осмотритесь](/search) и убедитесь, что вопрос [не был задан раньше](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Можно [задать вопрос и самостоятельно ответить на него](/helpcenter/self-answer). Всеобъемлющие, неясные, неполные и зависящие от личного мнения вопросы будут [заморожены](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) до тех пор, пока кто-то их не улучшит.

[Список советов, как задать хороший вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), который сообщество положительно оценит и привлечёт хорошие ответы.

**Некоторые вопросы считаются вопросами не по теме, хотя они и попадают в одну из категорий выше:**

1. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой ("почему этот код не работает?") должны включать желаемое повдение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. Вопросы, вызванные *проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой*. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до отправки вопроса.
3. Вопросы по домашним заданиям должны включать описание того, какую часть задачи вы уже решили, и в чём именно у вас возникли трудности.
4. Вопросы с просьбами *предоставить рекомендации или найти книги, инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие внешние ресурсы* являются на Stack Overflow оффтопиком, так как приводят к спорам и спаму. Вместо этого [опишите проблему](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399) и что вы сделали для её решения.
5. Вопросы про *аппаратное и программное обеспечение* являются оффтопиком, если только они не касаются напрямую инструментов, которые используются в основном при программировании.
6. Вопросы о *профессиональной администрации серверов, сетей и связанной инфрастурктуры* являются оффтопиком, если они не включают программирование или инструменты для программирования.

**Если ваш вопрос не подходит для Stack Overflow**, он может быть уместен на одном из [других сайтов сети Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

- Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com).
- Professional system and network administrators, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).
- Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).
- Database administrators and professionals, ask on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).
- SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Answer (score 0):

Исходник на английском в виде markdown (можно использовать в качестве образца).

---

### What topics can I ask about here?

Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel [the best Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question generally covers…

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer). Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be [put on hold by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) until they are improved.

[Click here for tips on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that are likely to be well-received by the community and attract good answers.

**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**

1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. Questions about *a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error*. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.
3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.
4. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.
5. Questions about *general computing hardware and software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.
6. Questions on *professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

**If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow**, it may be on topic for[another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If your question would be of interest to …

- Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com).
- Professional system and network administrators, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).
- Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).
- Database administrators and professionals, ask on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).
- SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.