# В вопросах без ответа висят некачественные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered

Особенно ужасны:

- [Предлагаю обсудить сортировку слиянием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/99375/182344)
- [C++ головоломки, что делают эти функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/144926/182344)

Я считаю, их нужно закрыть, чтобы они не подавали плохой пример. Прошу прощения, что это не вопрос, но ИМХО для новых пользователей важно, чтобы топ вопросов в любой сортировке был образцовым.

Comment: Вообще подобные штуки прекрасно укладываются в формат обычного форума. Но, насколько я понимаю, вовсе не в формат SO. Есть идеи по этому поводу, но фиг знает...

Comment: Надо закрыть - кидайте тервоги или закрытия.

Comment: Если вы видите вопросы, которые, по вашему мнению, следует удалить, пожалуйста, используйте возможность голоса за закрытие или за удаление. Мне кажется, приведенные вами вопросы далеко не "ужасные".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky один из них вообще не является вопросом! Увидимся на выборах модераторов :<

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko - сейчас я вас ввергну в уныние - Nicolas - сотрудник SO. И он останется с ромбом вне зависимости от результатов выборов.

Comment: @PashaPash на самом деле это даже лучше: если он сотрудник компании, значит он должен придерживаться ее политики, и можно связаться с его начальством, если не получится уладить разногласия мирно.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: ru.SO, как и все сайты сети StackExchange, управляется пользователями, то есть, нами. Забудьте об административных методах в стиле «я подействую на начальника, он сделает как мне нравится». Хотите добиться результата, убедите _всех нас_. В остальном работает _принцип валидации_.

Comment: @VladD надеюсь, вас не нужно убеждать, что вопрос в стиле "я сделаль" нуждается в закрытии :)

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: Нужно. Вопрос по любой теме может быть хорошим и плохим.

Comment: @VladD но "предлагаю обсудить сортировку слиянием" - это не вопрос. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: Вы правы, **тур** нужно подправить. Всё некогда.

Comment: @VladD тур прекрасен, не надо его трогать

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: Он по факту натолкнул вас на неверную мысль о том, какие вопросы _мы_ тут считаем хорошими. Значит, с туром проблемы. Я исправлю его.

Comment: @VladD Надеюсь, что это шутка юмора такая. Вам не для того права в транзифексе дадены, чтобы вы вандализм разводили.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, RU.SO не является полным идеологическим клоном SO. Почему -  Nicolas Chabanovsky не раз писал, почитайте посты из [meta-tag:faq]

Answer (score 6):

Не обсуждать, а закрывать надо. Идёте по списку вопросов и закрываете по 24 в день.

Так как у вас нет привилегии закрытия вопросов (500 репы), то орудуйте тревогами. Пока не выбьете 500 репы, у вас особый статус: в голосах вы ограничены сверху резиновым счётчиком тревог, а не фиксированным счётчиком голосов закрытия. Ловите момент. ;)

**Обновление**

У нас тут охлократия: из-за импорта данных с Хэшкода много юзеров с высокой репой, но из-за состояния беты низкие пороги на модерирование. В результате модерирует кто попало. Сообщество не согласилось с вашей оценкой этих вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/12562 (сортировка) — 2 закрыть, 3 открыть. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/12563 (головоломки) — 3 закрыть, 3 открыть (но добит @Nofate). Ну и к заплюсованным постам тут трепетно относятся, будто заплюсованного хлама не бывает. Закрывать такие вопросы сложно.

Comment: Я так вчера и сделал, но они все еще висят

Comment: @Discord http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?sort=votes&pageSize=50, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 - в обоих выборках половина топовых вопросов - хлам. Самые топовые заданы или отвечены текущими модераторами (Vlad там тоже репы нафармил). Предлагаете попросить Бармалея удалить его самый топовый вопрос с 36+ и 11 ответами? - удачи вам.

Comment: @PashaPash если не хотим очередной виноград, надо что-то с этим делать

Comment: @Discord хэшкод довольно долго использовался как чатик для разговоров по душам и для высказывания [страхов новичков](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76665/). все три текущих модератора активно в этом участвовали, и на этом нафармлена значительная часть их репутации (я не говорю что это плохо). Если nofate удалит все вопросы "по душам" и все "головоломки" - я буду не против. Но как бы его Бармалей с Николасом за такое не побили %)

Comment: @PashaPash: Я не модератор, окей?

Comment: @VladD не модератор. но репутацию тем менее нафармили (хоть и не в таких масштабах как Бармалей) :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Оставляя в стороне личный выпад («нафармили»), я считаю, что большинство вопросов, на которые я отвечал, интересны и достойны ответа. Какие-то проблемы с этим?

Comment: @VladD Никаких проблем. Извините если прозвучало как выпад, и за эмм.. жаргонизм. Я специально оставил замечание "я не говорю что это плохо". Скорее, я просто оцениваю удаление топовых вопросов "не по теме" как очень маловероятное, в том числе и потому, что текущие топовые пользователи считают их интересными и достойными ответа. И это их личное мнение, на которое я ни в коем случае не покушаюсь.

Answer (score 4):

Лично я не считаю забитый топ по голосам проблемой - это вообще самая бесполезная страница на SO. Самая ценная страница на SO - эта та, на которую человека приводит гугл. Но тем не менее:

Решение проблемы (если вы действительно считаете это проблемой):

- Не допускать нового хлама
- Постепенно минусовать и закрывать старый - еще раз упомяну что **голоса "против" за вопросы никак не влияют на вашу репутацию** - минусуйте все что видите. За максимум голосов в день медаль дают. А за за активное голосование по вопросам - даже золотую.
- Набрать критическую массу новых пользователей с репутацией для закрытия и удаления старого хлама. Сейчас, судя по количеству голосов, удалением пользуется два человека. А для удаления вопроса нужно от 3 до 10 голосов.

Возможно, есть какое-то более мягкое решение. Например, [блокировка вопросов как "исторически ценных"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) - на enSO такое успешно практикуется.

Успокоительная часть для старых пользователей:

Перенос контента с hashcode и статус беты вызвал несколько проблем:

- Низкие пороги модерации - закрывать вопросы могут, практически, случайные люди.
- Невозможность включить валидацию review - и некоторые пользователи жмут кнопки в ревью наугад, придерживаясь личных предпочтений, а не правил SO.
- Топы по основным меткам, которые внезапно оказались "оффтопиком" на SO.
- Низкий процент ответов и большое количество брошенных вопросов с накрученными (завышенными) показателями просмотров - что предотвращает их чистку ботом.

Это все пройдет - или постепенно, или по мере выхода из беты. Пороги поднимут, останется 10-20 активных людей с правом закрывать что-то. Новички будут вынуждены просидеть на сайте минимум полтора месяца для доступа к удалению, что охладит их пыл. Достаточно просто подождать.

Comment: Embrace, Extend and Extinguish.

Comment: @VladD Сайту 60 дней, как-то странно читать такое :) Хешкод умер, да здравствует SO!

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: Сообщество гораздо старше.

Comment: @VladD человек хотел план, я его предоставил. я же не говорю что удалять все подряд - хорошо :) И вообще я склоняюсь к правке вопросов, если их хоть как-то можно оживить.

Comment: @VladD у SE.com свои стандарты, не хотелось бы пропустить шанс понизить языковой барьер для программистов из-за сентиментальности

Comment: @VladD сообщество - это люди. а пока [в топе за месяц](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/month/ru-stackoverflow/2015-05-01?sort=reputationchange&pagesize=30) ровно половина - люди, котоыре пришли после hashcode. вопросы "за жизнь" за 11 год, авторы и отвечающие на которых уже давно не активны - это не сообщество.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: О, разговор медленно поворачивает в конструктивное русло от «мне не нравится» к «лучше/хуже для сайта». Мне не кажется, что данные вопросы плохи. По каждому из них высказались люди. Мне кажется, если сообщество явно высказало несогласие с вашим мнением, лучший путь — это либо попробовать переубедить сообщество, либо смириться.

Comment: @PashaPash: Да, изменения многих отпугнули. Extinguish уже происходит. Только не понимаю, почему вы априори считаете новых участников лучше старых?

Comment: @VladD с чего вы это взяли? Я всего лишь считаю, что существующая система репутации сломана из-за перевода большого количества контента с hashcode. Это приводит к **техническим** проблемам - кривой тур, невозможность включить валидацию review, низкий процент отвеченного (мешает выходу из беты) топ забитый "плохими" вопросами. Сами старые старые участники меня вполне устраивают (немного только напрягает неактивность их в мете и в инструментах модерирования)

Comment: @PashaPash: (1) Кривой тур. Подправить! К сожалению, у нас мало добровольцев-переводчиков. (2) Валидация ревью — не понял вопрос. (3) Низкий процент отвеченного — выровняется со временем, динамике должна быть положительной же? (4) плохие вопросы в топе — проблема плохих эвристик движка. Не контент надо подгонять под эвристики, а эвристики под контент.

Comment: @PashaPash: Старых участников отпугивают активные (обычно новые) участники, которые предлагают всё переделать как им нравится, и встречают поддержку таких же активных участников. Когда моё мнение будет постоянно в меньшинстве и минусоваться, поверьте, я тоже уйду с меты, а потом и с сайта.

Comment: @VladD (1) я не знаю по какому принципу выбирается вопрос для тура. рандом? (2) сейчас в ревью нет тестовых вопросов, за провал которых  ревьювер попадает в баг. выключено, насколько я понял, из-за большого количества старого неразобранного треша. (3) - да, но это мешает выходу из беты -> держит низкие пороги -> позволяет активным новичкам гнуть свою линию. (4) там сортировка по количеству голосов. вот и показываются вопросы 11-года "не по теме" с кучей плюсов.

Comment: @VladD а вы свое мнение выскажите в этом вопросе? а то пока минусовать или плюсовать нечего .

Comment: @PashaPash (1) И я не знаю (2) если баг, нужно пофиксить (команде, занимающейся движком) (3) выходу из беты мешают непрошедшие 90 дней, кстати (4) это и есть неправильно

Comment: @PashaPash: Вызов принят.

Comment: @VladD ну вот поэтому я сижу и "фармлю репу 10к минимум (с) Discord". проблема шустрых новичков отпадет сама собой после выхода из беты - порог в 3 к остановит.

Comment: @PashaPash, вопросы для тура выставляются вручную из ограниченного списка. Нужно уточнить у NicolasChabanovsky и можно поменять.

Answer (score 2):

Интернет странная штуковина, через четыре года он внезапно очнулся, чтобы закрыть тред, который я создал шутки ради четыре года назад, пока пытался создать 3D игру под Андроид.

То что скрипт считает его неотвеченным вопросом и он болтается наверху выдачи, никак не мои проблемы.

Сами куски кода, которые там есть весьма полезные:

1. Упаковка трех x,y,z координат точки в один float. Взято из Adreno SDK.
2. Быстрый способ округления до ближайшей степени двойки ассемблерной вставкой. Автора не помню, с какого-то американского форума.
3. Расчет 1/sqrt(x) взято из движка Quake3

Я безразлично отношусь к модерации в интернете и идеалистической идеи о высоких стандартах качества и необходимости выдерживать формат StackOverflow, поэтому делайте с ним что хотите. Хоть распечатайте и на стенку в туалете повесьте, если считаете что это Вам поможет научиться программировать нормально.

Comment: Ну так удалите, или закройте, или хотя бы ответьте сами и примите ответ

Comment: @igumnov: И это пройдёт. Подождите 2 недели.

Comment: @Alexei Дорогие Юлечка и Микурочка,  если бы новый сезон про вас не был бы такой [унылой, разочаровавшей меня, фансервисной штамповкой](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=10815) я бы может быть поддался ради вас приступу некрофилии и исправил бы что-нибудь в своем POST запросе 4 летней давности.  А теперь пусть с этим разбираются опытные некрофилы из очереди правок. Кроме того там в комментариях есть хороший ответ  +6 от покинувшего нас КотикХочетКушать.

Comment: @igumnov: Придётся пересматривать старые сезоны :-) Жизнь несправедлива к нам!

Comment: @Vlad Да на самом деле даже в оригинале довольно  паршивое и безыдейное аниме. Во втором сезоне одна и та же серия повторяется 8 раз подряд. С другой стороны [популярность песенки оттуда ужасает](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWB01IuMvzA), 20+ миллионов просмотров, даже [мозгоразрывающий опенинг Lucky Star переплюнуло](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_RPZcSZWJo).

Comment: @igumnov: Ну, такие ушки грех не пересмотреть ещё раз.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, вы решаете проблему не с той стороны.

Чтобы в топ попадали другие вопросы, нужно модифицировать эвристику отбора вопросов в топ. Подгонять контент под несовершенную эвристику — неверно, неправильно и на мой взгляд аморально. Подгонять нужно именно эвристику.

Например, понизить вес старых вопросов.

---

Кстати: то, что старые вопросы с ХэшКода, посещаемость которого была на порядок меньше посещаемости ru.SO, набрали больше баллов, чем набирают новые — это укор всем нам.

Хотите, чтобы хорошие ответы были в топе — отбросьте [нытьё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91), засучите рукава, и **дайте** хорошие ответы. А то покамест выходит претензии вида «наши ответы хуже старых, давайте закроем старые». Фу.

---

Если старый вопрос заплюсован — значит, он интересен и нужен людям. Вместо попытки закрыть его лучше подумайте, как дать на него хороший, качественный ответ. Не уничтожайте старое, а творите новое, лучшее. Тогда и в топе будут ваши ответы.

Comment: хороший призыв творить добро, но как вы предлагаете решать проблему "совсем-совсем заплюсованного оффтопика", на которую жалутется топикастер?

Comment: @PashaPash: Смотрите последний абзац. Заплюсованный офтопик = онтопик.

Comment: Я просто боюсь, что тема ru.SO уползет в сторону субъективных вопросов, и тогда плохо будет всем.

Comment: а что если новички приходят в старые-старые вопросы и пытаются отвечать? может все-таки лучше закрывать как "исторически ценный оффтопик"?

Comment: @VladD я про http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for - это именно для таких случаев механизим.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: По факту, активные пользователи не дадут сползти в эту сторону. Ну и офтопичные вопросы не так уж плохи время от времени.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы видите вопросы, которые, по вашему мнению, следует удалить, пожалуйста, используйте возможность голоса за закрытие или за удаление.

---

#### Старые вопросы

Мы знаем, что содержимое Stack Overflow на русском, как и Stack Overflow на любом другом языке - это прежде всего достояние сообщества, то есть если мы видим старый (новый) вопрос, который, по нашему мнению, каким-либо образом не соответствует тематике сообщества, то его надо либо улучшить, внеся правку, либо удалить.

Действительно, некоторые старые вопросы следует удалять, но только если они:

- несодержательные;
- не соответствуют тематике сообщества;
- не соответствуют формату Stack Overflow, в контексте самого вопроса, а не его оформления.

Например, так поступило сообщество с большинством вопросов по метке [хэшкод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4). Но это обуславливается не тем, что сами вопросы плохие, а тем, что хоть большенство сообщества Stack Overflow на русском перешло с ХэшКода, но мы сами внесли редакцию в наши правила. Сообщество приняло решение, что только вопросы напрямую относящиеся программированию, системному администрированию и настройке сложного ПО являются тематическими для Stack Overflow на русском (["На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/107/6)). Как результат, вопросы по метке [хэшкод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) стали "вне закона". В дополнение, я попытался отразить позицию относительно закрытия вопросов, которая, как мне кажется, за исключением, наверное, всеобъемлющих вопросов, поддерживается сообществом (["Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271/6)).

Исходя из этого, указанные в качестве примера вопросы, не относятся к тем, что подлежат удалению в связи с изменениями в правилах сообщества.

- Первый вопрос достаточно оформить, как вопрос с ответом самому себе. Его, и все вопросы подобные ему, не следует удалять, так как они соответствуют тематике форума. Подобные вопросы стали лишь не верно оформлены, так как в движке Stack Exchange отсутствуют исследования. Более того, такие вопросы содержат знания, потеряв которые, мы, сообщество Stack Overflow на русском, утратим часть нашего фундамента. Подчеркну, это не память или нечто подобное, это знания, которые полезны сообществу, то есть именно то, ради чего мы все здесь собрались.
- Второй вопрос также соответствует тематике, и также оформлен не верно. Точнее, не сам вопрос, а ответы к нему. Это уже ошибка модераторов ХэшКода. Скорее всего, верным решением в этом случае будет попросить участников обсуждения опубликовать их комментарии в виде ответов.

При этом, как мне кажется, сообщество поддержит удаление части старых вопросов ([например, тех, на которые указали в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76665/)).

Таким образом, подходите к удалению вопросов как можно более внимательно. Удаляя все подряд, мы рискуем потерять нечто важное. Вместо удаления, пожалуйста, всегда старайтесь внести улучшающую правку, которая позволит сделать наши усилия по обучению коллег еще более полезными.

Comment: Наконец-то взвешенный ответ от модератора. Ура!