# Где задавать не IT-шные вопросы на движке StackExchange?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, stackexchange

Я знаю три урла:

1. https://rus.stackexchange.com/

сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка.

2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

сайт для айтишников

3. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/

вопросы модерирования сайта для айтишников (развёрнуто написано здесь - 
[Обсуждение раздела справки "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/107))

У меня есть просто вопросы, но не знаю, где их позадавать.

Например - как легально утилизировать ртутные лампы в Москве (для физлиц)? Какими нормативно-правовыми актами регулируется процесс?

otvet.mail.ru использовать не хочется (там плохая политика).

Comment: Перегоревшие люминесцентные лампы можно отнести в свой районный ДЕЗ или РЭУ, где установлены специальные контейнеры. Там их должны бесплатно принять. Основанием для того, чтобы в ДЕЗе приняли у вас лампы, является распоряжение равительства Москвы «Об организации работ по централизованному сбору, транспортировке и переработке отработанных ртутьсодержащих люминесцентных и компактных люминесцентных ламп» от 19 мая 2010 года № 949-РП.

Comment: Пока нигде. Новые сайты можно предлагать на area51.stackexchange.com, но маловероятно, что они откроют сайт по российскому праву.

Comment: Не обязательно по праву. Вообще всё некомпьютерное. На самом деле, по-хорошему, надо создать фичу интегрирующую движок вопросов и википедию. Чтобы можно было задавать вопросы на любые темы, и потом переносить их поближе к наиболее подходящей по тематике статье википедии.

Comment: по другим темам это тоже маловероятно, к сожалению.

Comment: В России пилили клон Quora - odinotvet.ru -  для ответов на любые вопросы, но не взлетело. Можете почитать в сети постмортемы.

Comment: @hse5yzdx: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/234/181472

Comment: ну вообще помница мне, на хеш коде сайты для "других" вопросов были скорее мертвыми чем живыми:) так и тут наверное смысла открывать сообщества, если там будет несколько вопросов полутора годовалой давности. ...Но возможно имеет смысл открыть какой то общий канал для русско-язычных пользователей и уже по активности там можно выделять популярные направления вопросов(как на форумах были "болталки", "курилки", "общее").

Comment: @silksofthesoul: ну математика довольно живая там.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я тоже заметил:)

Comment: [TheQuestion.ru](https://thequestion.ru)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Боюсь, на данный момент в сети Stack Exchange нет других русскоязычных сообществ. На сколько мне известно, компания не планирует запуск сообществ на языках отличных от английского по тематикам не касающиеся информационных технологий.

В случае, если общение на английском приносит вам удовольствие, спешу порекомендовать обратить внимание [на список всех сайтов Сети](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Comment: Про весь список - это был хороший совет и к месту. Хотя общение на английском удовольствия и не приносит.

Comment: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack