# Раньше было интересно

Tags: обсуждение, раньше-было-лучше

Вынесенная в заголовок темы цитата промелькнула в чате в одной тем ("Да как-то вся атмосфера изменилась."). Я не уверен, что правильно понимаю смысл, который вкладывал сам автор в это утверждение, но очень хочу послушать других участников, согласны ли они с тем, что раньше было интересно или нет.
Этакое логичное развитие вопроса "[Зачем вы здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/213987)?".

Обсуждение свободное, возможно, какие-то ответы дадут пищу для раздумий руководству сообщества (чтобы отсрочить очередной ["Закат" Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4770/213987)), а я попробую угадать откуда может происходить подобный настрой.

Я вижу несколько вариантов.

Первая причина заключается в том, что вопросы стали неинтересные. Эта тема уходит корнями в то, что [so превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/213987).

Второй момент идёт от того, что очень сильно "убивается  живое общение".

Надо понимать, что несмотря на то, что [so как платформа имеет черты блога, форума](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/691/213987), социальная составляющая не является основной целью, основная цель - создать базу знаний.

> Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов, который
>   существенно отличается от традиционных интернет-форумов
>   (дискуссионных-форумов), объединяя в себе черты вики-энциклопедий,
>   коллективных блогов, лент новостей и собственно форумов.

[image: сайт вопросов и ответов]

Общение профессионалов понимается как возможность задать вопрос и получить ответ и хватит вам.

Я не застал эпоху хешкода, возможно тогда оффтопика и общения в комментариях было больше, но я вижу, что сейчас комментарии последовательно и постепенно компания собирается изжить как зловредный "шум". (Николас [писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7105/213987) " комментарии — это сущность второго плана", в идеальном мире не нужны — я писал [отдельный ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7109/213987) на это).

Не удивлюсь, если после введения [новой формы вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7219/213987), вызванной дискриминацией новичков, женщин, цветных и маргинализированных слоёв, комментарии будут вообще удалены и возможности общения станет ещё меньше (уж не в комментах точно и не на мете — выдавливается в чаты). И у нас нет возможности ни [задавать вопросы за рамками тематических](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/708/213987) (даже просто расширить онтопик на смежные с ИТ-темы непросто) ни общаться более неформально под вопросами. Число правил и регламентов обязательных для участников увеличивается, отдельный вопрос по части того, что некоторые участники считают что "насаждается принудительный бинайс".

Третий момент заключается в том, что компания проводит изменения, которые воспринимаются как уменьшающие число демократических процедур. Частично я писал об этом в [этой теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7221/213987), но в одну не поместилось и подумываю ещё одну создать.

И четвёртый момент я вижу в том, что мы постепенно взрослеем и интересы наши меняются. То есть не сайт стал плохим — просто мы сами выросли. Причина более актуальна для тех, кто по 3-4 года сидит на сайте, чем для тех, кто год-два. Этакая причина из серии "раньше трава была зеленее".

В принципе, это всё, что у меня есть сказать по этому поводу. А дальше я бы с интересом послушал другие мнения. Повторяю ещё раз свои вопросы:

> А как вы сами оцениваете, было ли раньше интереснее? Почему?

Comment: вопрос похож по структуре: *"вы перестали бить жену, да или нет?"*

Comment: @jfs: И вы, конечно, можете опубликовать ответ с подробным разбором того, что в вопросе не так?

Answer (score 13):

Не знаю, стоит ли что-то добавлять, но выскажусь по пунктам со своей колокольни.

> Первая причина заключается в том, что вопросы стали неинтересные. Эта
>   тема уходит корнями в то, что [so превращается в консультационный
>   пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/213987).

Да, собственно, нет. Всегда были "детские" вопросы. Просто, мне кажется, деды в первые годы с большей охотой на них отвечали. А после пятого, десятого, сотого вопроса охладели к ним.

> Второй момент идёт от того, что очень сильно "убивается  живое общение".

Любимый некоторым термин "информационный шум"... Очень удобная фраза, которая не несёт почти никакого смысла. Сторонники удаления "шума" часто ссылаются на то, что "на форумах из-за такого шума невозможно было найти нужный ответ". Вот только SO по структуре не похож на форумы. Комментарии никак не "загрязняют" страницу, не мешают нахождению ответа на странице и т.п

Зато комментарии очень часто раскрывают особенности ответа/вопроса и там реально интересные беседы бывают, опять же, которые не вредят вопросу как таковому.

И мне вообще непонятна эта мания на выпиливание комментариев. КМ недавно в чате вообще заявил, что "после того, как ответ дан и зааксепчен автором вопроса, нужно удалять все комментарии"...

> Третий момент заключается в том, что компания проводит изменения,
>   которые воспринимаются как уменьшающие число демократических процедур.
>   Частично я писал об этом в [этой
>   теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7221/213987), но в одну не
>   поместилось и подумываю ещё одну создать.

Да демократии тут, собственно, никогда не было. Но раньше не было ощущения, что сообщество ничего не решает.

> И четвёртый момент я вижу в том, что мы постепенно взрослеем и
>   интересы наши меняются. То есть не сайт стал плохим - просто мы сами
>   выросли. Причина более актуальна для тех, кто по 3-4 года сидит на
>   сайте, чем для тех, кто год-два. Этакая причина из серии "раньше трава
>   была зеленее".

Я на хешкод и SO пришёл совсем зелёным.Тогда больше искал ответы на свои вопросы, нежели сам отвечал на вопросы других. Потом, на след. стадии, я уже мог помогать другим, попутно продолжая задавать вопросы.

И вот, по прошествии лет, я думаю это ко многим относится, чувствую, что, хм, перерос(?) SO. Я сталкиваюсь с проблемами, в решении которых вполне вероятно, SO не сможет мне помочь, вопросы будут закрыты, как минимум на en SO, как "узкоспециализированные".

Мне это, в общем-то, напоминает практически любой форум, на которых раньше люди сидели. По прошествии лет и сотен обсужденных тем человеку это уже малоинтересно, и он, если и продолжает оставаться на форуме, то в пассивном режиме.

Comment: Про комментарии особенно согласен. По моему мнению, **лишнего не должно быть в сообщениях — т. е. вопросах и ответах**. А комментарии не хочешь — не читай. И **1.** затрачиваемое на борьбу с комментариями время; **2.** негативная реакция пользователей, чьи комментарии удаляются; **3.** возможная польза от комментариев; — перевешивают плюсы от удаления. Спасибо.

Comment: Невольно начинаешь задумываться - если новички всегда будут задавать одни и те же вопросы, то какая вообще польза от базы ответов, если нужно постоянно заново отвечать? Или же нужно реорганизовать в *первую Галактическую* более навязчивый формат?

Comment: @Other если прям одни и те же, то закрывать как дубли)

Comment: Эх, больная тема. Мало того, что каноничных вопросов нет (разве что парочка, типа вопроса по асинхронщине в JS), так ещё надо искать вопросы, выбирать какой именно тут подходит на 100%. Нет тут возможности адресации на библиотеку SO (на EnSO вроде есть что-то вроде учебника по разным вещам).