# Где можно задать вопрос про лицензирование Windows?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, тематика

Здравствуйте, есть вопрос про лицензирование MS Windows. 
Есть англоязычный сайт superuser.com, есть ли его аналог на русском языке?
Или где можно задать вопрос про лицензирование?

Comment: A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away.... был РутКод и БитКод, но они не взлетели. Теперь остается только обратно на stackoverflow.ru . Но минусаторы уже наточили свои минусовалки и ехидно осматриваются вокруг в поисках новой жертвы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, в чем именно вопрос? Есть ли аналог SuperUser или где задать вопрос про лицензирование?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хочу получить ответы на оба вопроса. В superuser можно задавать вопросы про лицензии.

Answer (score 4):

**Стоит ли задавать вопросы о программном обеспечении на Stack Overflow на русском?**

На данный момент в сети Stack Exchange существует только одно русскоязычное сообщество связанное с IT - это Stack Overflow на русском. Согласно тому, что я знаю, компания не планирует запуск других сообществ на языках, на которых уже запущен Stack Overflow (португальский, японский и русский, сообщество ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) очень редкое исключение)

НО! Сообществом [было принято решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/154/6), что для Stack Overflow на русском будут соответствовать тематике вопросы касающиеся:

- разработки программного обеспечения;
- системного администрирования;
- настройки сложного ПО.

[Подробнее в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Таким образом, если ваш вопрос был бы тематичен для SuperUser.com, с большой вероятностью он будет тематичен и для Stack Overflow на русском.

**Стоит ли задавать конкретно упомянутый вами вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском?**

Однозначно ответить нельзя, так как это напрямую зависит от:

- собственно, вашего вопроса;
- его оформления;
- есть ли в сообществе участники, заинтересованные тематикой вопроса.

Таким образом, если ваш вопрос можно отнести к [тематике сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), он качественно оформлен и сообщество его приняло (вопрос не закрыт, имеет положительную оценку и получил один и более ответ), то вы правильно поступили, когда задали его.

Comment: А разве пункт _Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если они не уникальны к программированию_ среди _Вопросы по теме, но которые не стоит задавать_ в справке не говорит о том, что вопрос _как получить лицензию для Windows?_ является вопросом не по теме?

Comment: @Regent Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Вопросы жанра Super User задавать бесполезно, потому что они будут закрыты в большинстве случаев, чего бы ни фантазировали о широте тематики отдельные пользователи. Однозначно уместны только вопросы про ПО для программистов (которые подходят для Stack Overflow) и в немного меньшей мере вопросы для сисадминов и смежных профессий (которые подходят для Server Fault).

Вопросы про лицензирование винды с большой вероятностью завернут даже на английском Super User, потому что с такими вопросами нужно обращаться в саппорт Майкрософта.

Comment: там можно задавать такие вопросы: [tagged/license](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license).  Звонил в MS, два разных оператора дали противоречивые ответы.

Comment: @Ildar Позвоните в третий раз. Тогда, если повезёт, будете иметь два голоса против одного. :)

Comment: @Discord вы с саппортом ms просто не общались. там столько индусов, и несут они такую пургу, особенно когда дело касается биллинга, что ни на один ответ нельзя положиться.

Comment: Кстати, а почему "**в немного меньшей мере** вопросы для сисадминов и смежных профессий"? Не вижу причин, почему бы это было в меньшей мере.

Comment: @NickVolynkin На сайте достаточно высокореповых юзеров с не очень положительным отношением к вопросам о сисадминстве, поэтому риск, что вопрос будет закрыт, несколько выше.