# Соответствие тематике сайта вопросов об инструментах программиста не в контексте программирования

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, тематика

[Справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся: (...) к инструментам для разработки: языкам программирования, средам, операционным системам, пакетам программ, фреймворкам, библиотекам;

но

> Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: (...) Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если они не относятся к программированию или системному администрированию.

К сожалению, нельзя посмотреть историю коммитов для страниц справки, почему затруднительно узнать, кем и по итогам каких обсуждений были внесены данные фразы.

Между тем [итогами опроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2776/199934) запрещены вопросы по использованию программного обеспечения — из текста следует, что любого, без каких-либо исключений.

Однако [данным ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/719/199934) утверждается, что вопросы по «настройке сложного ПО» допустимы, при этом не приводится уточнения, что вопросы о сложном ПО для программистов допустимы только тогда, когда они **только** связаны с программированием.

Запутался, прошу оценить на соответствие тематике сайта следующие конкретные вопросы, на мой взгляд прямо не относящихся к программированию:

---

- [Как в Sublime Text 3 изменить шрифт текста в Side Bar?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435917/199934)

Вопрос об изменении визуальных характеристик программы.

- [Sublime Text 3 — обзор папок при помощи FTP плагина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497892/199934)

Автору вопроса неудобна особенность Sublime Text.

- [Предпросмотр правок без внесения изменений в Википедию или другой вики-сайт при их редактировании посредством Sublime Text 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503052/199934)

Вопрос, минусование и закрытие которого побудило создать данную тему.

- [How to make scroll bar indicator more clear and easy to see?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31093497/5951529) (из en SO)

Плохо виден бегунок.

- [Перетаскивание текста в редакторе Brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507976/199934)

Приведём пример не только для Sublime Text.

- [Вертикальная полоса в phpStorm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/332068/199934)

Вопрос о «полновесном» IDE. Если что, плагины делают и из Sublime Text [почти полноценную интегрированную среду разработки](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=Sublime+Text+IDE).

---

Какие вопросы допускать, а когда их авторам рекомендовать обратиться к сообществу англоязычного Stack Overflow, где ни один из похожих вопросов (говорю за Sublime Text) не закроют?

Answer (score 2):

Вы откопали какой-то странный заблокированный вопрос, в котором заминусованы все ответы, и делаете на его основании какие-то выводы. Так делать не надо.

В справке описаны правила в актуальном состоянии. Если после обсуждения на Мете что-то решают изменить, то вносят соответствующие исправления. (За исключением свежих проблем: процесс долгий всё-таки.)

В вашем списке обсуждаются средства для разработки приложений, споров об их уместности нет и никогда не было.

Ну и в целом, чтобы избежать подобных вопросов в будущем: что можно на большом СО, то можно на русском, однако обратное неверно.

Comment: По абзацам: // **[1]** — *а)* В решении по закрытию этот опрос назван даже [историческим](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2775/199934), *б)* За варианты было отдано по 19 голосов — больше, чем обычно. Считаю, что подобные ответы наоборот имеют больший вес в сравнении с теми, за которые было отдано несколько голосов, т. к. в отражают оценочное мнение большего процента из числа активных участников мета-сообщества. // **[2]** Спасибо, принял к сведению.

Comment: // **[3]** Вопрос, где [Вы указали](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/515714/revisions) мне, как оформлять код, [объявлен требующим правки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503052/199934). Это и послужило открытию данной темы. // **[4]** Этот же вопрос, заданный на английском Stack Overflow, [не закрыли](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36266019/5951529).

Comment: @СашаЧерных "Историческая блокировка" переводится как "мусор, но удалять жалко". У вас интересное представление о результатах голосования, оно не соответствует сложившейся практике. Редактирование с помощью языка разметки уже не очень относится к программированию, а в этом вопросе вовсе сообщается о баге в стороннем плагине — СО для таких вопросов банально нелогично использовать, надо писать в багтрекер приложения.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Тут вообще тонкая материя: если бы вопрос звучал как "настройка подсветки markdown в Visual Studio для редактирования ReadMe на GitHub", отношение было бы другим. Тут же редактирование статей на в каких-то левых вики — задача скорее уровня Super User, поэтому и отношение соответствующее. Приводить в пример большой СО большого смысла нет, потому что там большой траффик, и при паре десятков просмотров и непопулярных метках вопросы банально остаются без должной проверки. И опять-таки: тонкая материя. Если этот вопрос попадёт в очередь на закрытие на большом СО, то его запросто зароют.

Comment: > надо писать в багтрекер приложения — *а)* Мой вопрос не о конкретном баге, а о цели — как реализовать просмотр вики-разметки, — пусть и потребуются другие инструменты. Собственно, разрешилась проблема совершенно другим плагином. // *б)* Я [сообщил](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer/issues/93) о баге разработчикам плагина, и не получив ответа, разрешающего мои проблемы, обратился на русский и английский SO со своим вопросом. Помимо моей там висят [ещё 34](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer/issues) незакрытые проблемы.

Comment: Насчёт «левых вики» ответил [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503052/Предпросмотр-правок-без-внесения-изменений-в-Википедию-или-другой-вики-сайт-при#comment635993_515714). Ну а о том, где же эта «тонкая материя» — грань между запрещёнными вопросами и нет — и есть данный мой вопрос.