# Жизненный цикл вопроса на Stack Overflow

Tags: поддержка, faq

Очевидно, некоторые участники, [которым, на самом деле, нужно быть более вдумчивыми](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245/michaelpryor), испытывают затруднения с пониманием принципа работы Stack Overflow. Мы воспринимаем это как камень в огород существующей [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/faq) (как официальной, так и неофициальной).

Stack Overflow по сути своей является сайтом вопросов и ответов. Поэтому **жизненный цикл любого вопроса**, по определению, относится к механизму работы сайта. Сегодня мы решили собрать своеобразный дайджест, самое главное и основное:

### Stack Overflow – сообщество разработчиков программного обеспечения

Начнем с того, что, [если ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/a-question-about-questions/) (а также [системному администрированию или настройки сложного ПО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), ему не место на Stack Overflow. Что можно назвать вопросом, имеющим отношение к программированию? Вот полный перечень, [сформулированный самим сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/154/6):

- к конкретной задаче программирования: коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
- к инструментам для разработки: языкам программирования, средам, операционным системам, пакетам программ, фреймворкам, библиотекам;
- к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;
- к настройке физических и виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их настройки, мониторинга и автоматизации процессов;
- к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем.

Посмотрите на этот перечень и спросите себя: **Соответствует ли мой вопрос тематике?** Если ответ положительный – прекрасно! Публикуйте вопрос незамедлительно! Если он не соответствует правилам, не надо себя в этом винить: это значит, что вы сможете задать ваш вопрос где-то еще. Если, тем не менее, вы задаете вопрос, не соответствующий тематике Stack Overflow, тогда…

### Кто принимает решение о том, соответствует ли вопрос тематике сайта?

Решение о соответствии вопроса тематике сайта принимают участники сообщества, имеющие достаточную для этого репутацию. Каждый вопрос проходит процедуру проверки сообществом.

1. Вы видите вопрос, который не соответствует тематике Stack Overflow, поскольку [не относится к программированию](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/a-question-about-questions/).
2. Ваша репутация составляет 3 000 баллов – необходимый минимум для голосования за закрытие или открытие вопросов.
3. Вы голосуете за закрытие вопроса.
4. Четверо других участников также голосуют за закрытие вопроса, при этом суммарное число голосов за его закрытие составляет пять (5) (или же за закрытие вопроса голосует модератор, голос которого закрывает вопрос вне зависимости от суммарного числа голосов).
5. После закрытия вопрос может быть открыт повторно, после аналогичного голосования. Если вопрос набирает пять (5) голосов за повторное открытие, процесс начинается с пункта №3.
6. Если вопрос **остается закрытым в течение полных 48 часов**, он допускает возможность удаления.
7. Ваша репутация составляет 10 000 баллов – необходимый минимум для голосования за удаление вопросов.
8. Если вопрос получает три голоса за удаление (или голос модератора), вопрос удаляется.
9. Обратите внимание, что удаленные вопросы невидимы для рядовых участников, но видны модераторам и участникам с репутацией больше 10 000.
10. Удаленный вопрос в любой момент может быть восстановлен – после процедуры голосования. Если вопрос набирает три голоса за восстановление, процесс начинается с пункта №7.

Да, процесс несовершенен, потому что время от времени не удается достичь единодушного согласия по тому или иному вопросу. Если вас это удивляет, нам бы хотелось тактично напомнить, что для вида homo sapience, которым, среди прочих, населена наша планета, несогласие, верьте иль не верьте, *абсолютно нормально*.

(Хотим заметить, наличие несерьезных вопросов, связанных с программированием – а таковые периодически становятся популярными в сообществе – вполне допускается; главное, чтобы их не было слишком много).

### Почему вы позволяете удалять содержимое сайта?

Жизнь и смерть идут рука об руку, и, как мы полагаем, [удаление содержимого – также довольно неприятное, но вполне нормальное явление в жизни сайта](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/).

Кто может удалять вопросы?

- **Авторы сообщений** могут удалять свои ответы. Вопросы же могут быть удалены только в том случае, если среди ответов нет ни одного с достаточно высоким рейтингом.
- **Участники с репутацией более 10 000** могут удалять вопросы, которые были закрыты в течение хотя бы 48 часов, если наберется три (3) голоса за удаление. Удаленные вопросы могут быть восстановлены – процедура восстановления вопроса аналогична процедуре его удаления.
- **Модераторы** могут удалять любой вопрос.

Зачем нужно *удалять* вопрос? Неужели недостаточно просто закрыть его?

- Некоторые вопросы имеют настолько низкий уровень, что не заслуживают пощады. Увы, но не каждый байт данных на этом свете достоин бессмертия.
- Некоторые вопросы настолько не соответствуют тематике сайта, что не несут никакой пользы сообществу.
- Мыслительные усилия, затрачиваемые участниками на просмотр закрытых вопросов, отнюдь не равны нулю – особенно это актуально для участников, которые активно вовлечены в жизнь сообщества и постоянно просматривают списки вопросов в поисках тех, на которые они могут предложить свой ответ.
- Если участники будут видеть большое количество закрытых вопросов, они заметят, что мы не следуем правилам, и сами не будут им следовать. Без окончательного вердикта по каждому вопросу мы потеряем то, что неявно поощряем, а именно – [«теорию разбитых окон»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD) в применении к жизни сообщества. Если это будет продолжаться достаточно долго, нас больше нельзя будет назвать сообществом разработчиков программного обеспечения, которые задают вопросы о программировании и отвечают на них: мы станем сообществом случайных людей, беседующих на вольные темы, а это деструктивно.
- Если количество закрытых, но не удаленных вопросов возрастет до определенного предела, они станут загромождать пространство, снижая отношение сигнала к шуму – и доверие к системе.

Буду откровенен: мы ни в коей мере не считаем удаление вопросов самоцелью. Но мы уверены, что **недостаточная решимость при отбраковке некачественного содержимого** гораздо более опасна для сообщества, чем попустительство к слабым вопросам в напрасной надежде, что со временем они каким-то магическим образом улучшатся.

Надеюсь, эта публикация поможет устранить непонимание в том, что касается жизненного цикла вопроса на Stack Overflow.

---

Это свободный перевод публикации «[The Stack Overflow Question Lifecycle](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/)».

Comment: Я считаю, что пункт `Если участники будут видеть большое количество закрытых вопросов, они заметят, что мы не следуем правилам, и сами не будут им следовать.` требует дополнительного пояснения. Мне он кажется абсолютно неясным. Какова связь между большим количеством закрытых вопросов и не следованию правилам? Наоборот, закрытые вопросы означают, что за сайтом следят и неформат удаляется...

Comment: Имеется в виду, что на сайте есть большое количество вопросов, которые следовало бы удалить, но они все еще «живые». Это достаточно старая, но на мой взгляд, интересная публикация. Раньше все удалялось руками, силами модераторов и активных участников сообщества. В последствии появилась [система автоматического удаления заброшенных вопросов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/).

Comment: Следует заметить, что без предыстории сложно вынести основной посыл поста, кроме справочной информации. Как я понял из комментариев, пост написан еще и потому, что имела место быть следующая последовательность: `Написан ответ к вопросу` → `Вопрос закрыт, как несоответствующий тематике`