# Вопросы с БитКода: считать ли офтопиком?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Мне сегодня [сообщили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2615/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#comment8551_2753), что вопросы по тематике БитКода (вопросы юзеров по работе с ПО), в отличии от РутКода (вопросы по системному администрированию), считаются на ruSO офтопиком.

> Руткод вошел в онтопик, Биткод - нет. *(c) [Nofate ♦](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate)*

Я, мягко говоря, удивился, так как на самом БитКоде висит [заглушка](http://user.hashcode.ru/stackoverflow/) (выводится после авторизации на сайте), приглашающая задавать вопросы на ruSO, а приглашать людей на сайт, где их вопросы видеть не хотят - крайне странно.

Дальше больше: до того, ночью, вычищая мета-метки, натыкаюсь на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/322740/14756) двухлетней давности, получивший низкокачественный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/322741/14756) с припиской

> P.S: подобного рода вопросы (проблемы с программным обеспечением и т.п.) лучше задавать на БитКоде

Сам вопрос банален, но вполне каноничен, для БитКода. Более того, ещё и полугода не прошло, как я боролся с такой же "банальной" проблемой на протяжении n дней, пока сосед - геймер и хардварщик (не программист, в этом он, как раз, не смыслит) не посоветовал проверить ярлыки. "Стандартные" ответы, вроде "проверьте комп антивирусом" не помогли, потому что вируса-то и не было: браузер сам ставил этот плагин при каждом запуске. То есть, при всей банальности вопроса, полный и качественный ответ на него далеко не банален и представляет из себя целый алгоритм по проверке компьютера (ручками, антивирус против человеческой хитрости, увы, бессилен).

Понимая, что банальные вопросы задаются чаще всего, а желающих каждый раз на них развёрнуто отвечать нет, я отредактировал вопрос, убрал ссылку на БитКод из старого ответа и написал канонический ответ, в котором изложил алгоритм удаления вредоносного расширения из любого браузера. Пришёл модератор плюсанул, по его собственным словам, ответ и сказал:

> Данный вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию. *(с) [Nick Volynkin ♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin)*

То есть уже два модератора считают, что вопросы по тематике БитКода - неформат. Я удивился ещё больше и пошёл спрашивать в чате, где получил [ответ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28480774#28480774), окончательно меня запутавший:

> Более того, согласно ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic на сайте можно
>   задавать вопросы о программных продуктах, но их, как мы видим нет. На
>   мой взгляд, сообщество не создавало барьеров, тем более искусственных,
>   просто нам это не интересно. *(с) [Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144267)*

При этом, в самом [приведённом разделе справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), указано следующее:

> #### Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:
>
> ...
>
> - Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если они не относятся к программированию.

Самое смешное, что под этот пункт справки, подпадают и вопросы по системному администрированию, присутствующие на сайте как наследие РутКода и являющиеся онтопиком, по общему мнению модераторов.

Так, простите, мы "не создаём искусственных барьеров", или закрываем вопросы, как неформат, дорогое сообщество? И если закрываем, то зачем заглушка на БитКоде? А если закрываем не все, но некоторые, то какие критерии **хорошего вопроса от юзера** вы предлагаете и почему? По результатам обсуждения предлагаю отредактировать соответствующий раздел справки, и, в дальнейшем, исходить из него.

**UPD:** Тем временем, не только мой ответ (который многие плюсуют за качество, абстрагировавшись от вопроса), но и сам вопрос продолжают собирать плюсы. В очередной раз видно, что мнение активного сообщества (того, которое сидит в чате и читает Мету) и пассивного (того, что просто задаёт вопросы, отвечает на них и голосует, не вникая во внутреннюю политику сайта) сильно различается. ИМХО, с этим надо что-то делать.

Comment: Нет таких критериев. Смотрите на эту проблему шире. **Зачем, вообще, удалять вопросы** (кроме откровенного бреда), имеющие отношение к компьютерам? ***В чем конкретная цель?***  / Плохие вопросы засоряют сайт? - Реально, приходящий сюда видит одну страницу новых вопросов. / Поиск по ключевым словам на сайте? - Достаточно организовать вывод, упорядоченный по заплюсованным ответам и автоматически удалять старые неотвеченные вопросы.

Comment: @avp у меня (у сына, точнее) в майнкрафте заедает кнопка "вперед". вопрос имеет отношение к компьютерам. значит можно задавать, с тегами [tag:java], [tag:windows] и [tag:клавиатура]?

Comment: @PashaPash, пусть задает. А вот отвечать не надо.

Comment: @avp т.е. Risto тоже не стоило отвечать на вопрос о прикладном ПО? Чем майнкрафт отличается от хрома (в плане оффтопичности вопросов по использованию, а не разработки под него)? Почему Risto может ответить на вопрос, который вообще никакого отношения к программированию не имеет, и наловить плюсов, а я - не должен. Несправедливо как-то.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите  примеры вопросов, которые относятся к тематике БитКода / SuperUser и при этом являются качественными, четко описанными и воспроизводимыми ([mcve])

Comment: @PashaPash, если бы речь шла о заедании клавиатуры, то нет (не надо отвечать). Вы же понимаете, что вопрос-то о границах и о том, что большинство закрывальщиков эти границы плохо ощущает. Поэтому и столь радикальное предложение. Более реальное сведется к определению границ допуска в закрывальщики. Замкнутый круг.

Comment: @avp нет, клавиатура в порядке, просто Cтив продолжает бежать вперед при отпускании кнопки. какой-то глюк minecraft. или java - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/why-does-my-character-walk-forward-automatically - 33 плюса кстати. Вот попробуйте описать строгий критерий, по которому пользование хромом - онтопик, а бег Стива - нет.

Comment: @PashaPash ни то, ни другое, не оффтопик, по критериям БитКода. Более того, на вопрос в течении суток был дан конкретный ответ, насколько я вижу. Чем он вам не угодил? По мне, так вопросы типа "Ааа, у миня цыкл ни рабоит, ни знаю пачему, памагите!!!" - куда большая проблема.

Comment: @PashaPash, ага! Ситуация изменилась. Вы хотите сказать, что если клавиатура в порядке, то решение "оставить" приведет сюда легион обсуждальщиков игрушек и мы получим совершенно неприемлимую ситуацию даже на главной странице (не получится же сразу сделать для них русскоязычный раздел (или как это называется?)). Если честно, не знаю, что делать. Я бы рискнул и попробовал оставить, а вот если они реально станут мешать, тогда уж все такое и удалить (вместе с аккаунтами).

Comment: @avp фокус в том, что если "обсуждальщиков игрушек" будет **реально** столько, что они заполонят сайт - проблемы пробить них ruGaming и перенести туда со всеми вопросами не будет. То же самое с обсуждальщиками вирусов, Хрома, чёрта в ступе.

Comment: @avp на главной проскакивают вопросы по word/excel/minecraft - но их достаточно быстро закрывают и минусуют. Суть этого вопроса на мете - не минусовать и не закрывать.

Comment: @Risto пробить ruGaming - нереально, насколько я знаю. посещаемость даже en-SU - низкая, ru-SU нам, соответственно, тоже не светит. Т.е. мы окажемся в ситуации, когда вопросы "как сделать шрифт в ворде жирным" - онтопик (на основании вот этого же обсуждения), и переносить их - некуда.

Comment: @PashaPash давайте воспользуемся логикой. Есть две возможных ситуации, если разрешить вопросы юзеров: (1) Вопросов и ответов по этой тематике будет мало, на работе сайта это не скажется или скажется незначительно. (2) Набежит огроменная толпа спрашивающих, за ней - такая же толпа отвечающих, охочих до своих лайков, как вы боитесь. Но если их будет такая толпа, то и проблем пробить им свой сайт не будет.

Comment: @Risto, все правильно. Железная логика. Собственно, осталось только взять и проверить.

Comment: @Risto Есть ещё вариант: толпа набежит такого размера, что она будет достаточной для раздражения, но недостаточной для отдельного сайта. :)

Comment: @Risto SE, насколько я знаю, явно дал понять, что остальные сайты локализовать не будут. Они сделали исключение для [rus.stackexchange.com](http://rus.stackexchange.com/) - и то очень криво, без меты. Дело не в толпе - ее не будет, судя по посещаемости enSU. У сайта есть тематика - программирование и администрирование. Вы предлагаете разбавить ее низкокачественными вопросами от обычных пользователей, практически без возможности их куда-то потом переселить - лично мне эта идея не нравится.

Comment: @Discord я тут нашёл ваш комментарий (и ответ Николаса) в теме по SF http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%9f%d0%9e-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81?rq=1#comment436_234 Он ещё актуален? Если да, то это очень печально.

Comment: @PashaPash я пару дней назад туда заглядывал. Всё там есть, и Мета тоже.

Comment: @Risto На отделение Ru.SF и Ru.SU я бы не рассчитывал, учитывая заявления администрации и вообще всё связанное с локализованными сайтами. Насчёт [Меты Rus.SE](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/) не понял. По моим ощущениям, импорт Rus.SE — это попытка спасти полезный груз с корабля, который решили затопить, то есть исключение сделано лишь потому, что контент уже есть, а оставлять его в Сети Знаний — обрекать на гибель. Впрочем, это исключительно мои ощущения, на правду не претендую.

Comment: @Risto Русский язык – отдельная тема. До перехода на платформу SE, сообщество развивалось гораздо быстрее сообщества разработчиков. К пример, на сколько помню, количество переходов их поиска в пересчете на один вопрос в базе было раз в десять выше чем у ХэшКода. Количество переходов – один из показателей качества содержимого.

Comment: @Discord мета rus практически мертва - 36 вопросов, пара десятков посещений. Для взлета отдельного сайта нужно сообщество (или хотя бы его зачатки). Легиона обсуждальщиков игрушек / фанатов ворда не будет - у них есть свои устоявшиеся тусовки. Будут одиночные вопросы, причем низкокачественные (судя по тем, что задаются сейчас). Т.е. даже если формально расширить тему - ни к каким изменениям это не приведет. Расширять же тему ради полутора вопросов в месяц - лично я считаю излишним.

Comment: @PashaPash давайте посмотрим, какое количество **просмотров** соберёт мой ответ про удаление расширений (мне было обещано, что вопрос просто закроют, но не удалят), скажем, за год, а затем уже поговорим о "зачем это нужно". Фишка в том, что на подобные вопросы достаточно подробно ответить один раз (все подобные вопросы "как удалить плагин  XXX из FF" теперь можно отмечать копиями отвеченного), а дальше получать траффик юзеров, **ежедневно** сталкивающихся с этой проблемой.

Comment: @Risto в мире полно проблем, имеющих отношение к компьютерам, но не имеющих отношения к разработке, которые наберут **на порядок больше** просмотров. Навскидку - "как поставить мелодию на iphone" или "как удалить вирусы". То, что вопрос кому-то интересен, и кто-то с ним ежедневно сталкивается - еще не повод менять онтопик.

Answer (score 13):

Сообщество и администрация **не смогли прийти к консенсусу** насчёт тематик Super User и Server Fault на Stack Overflow на русском. Как следствие, имеем противоречия в справке, споры вокруг допустимости вопросов, открывания-перезакрывания и прочий бардак.

Почему нет консенсуса?

С одной стороны находится администрация, которая выступает за инклюзионизм: "тематики SU и SF приветствуются". Аргументация простая: отдельных сайтов на русском для тем SU и SF нет и никогда не будет, потому что они не смогут вырасти до достойного размера. Банальная арифметика: берём количество юзеров на SO, SF, SU, SO.RU, считаем пропорцию, получаем примерно ноль (в масштабах Stack Exchange).

С другой стороны находится часть старичков большого Stack Overflow, которая выступает за удализм: "что уместно на большом SO, то и здесь". Аргументация простая: если дать свободу, то в целом программистский сайт будет завален вопросами "как поставить ворд", что превратит сайт в помойку и отпугнёт посетителей.

Вариант "можно SF, нельзя SU" — это имитация консенсуса в сложившейся ситуации. Но так как консенсуса нет, то правил нет, а вопросы открываются и закрываются по желанию левой пятки высокореповых юзеров.

---

И пусть меня поправит Николас, если это не так, но, думаю, ему гораздо интереснее работать над проектами Stack Exchange. Всё, что было ценного, было импортировано из Сети Знаний. Теперь старые сайты — так, реликты прошлого. Собственно, главная страница Сети Знаний редиректит на СО.

Comment: Когда возможности достичь консенсуса в дилемме или трилемме исчерпаны, на авансцену должно выходить  **аргументированное волевое решение** в пользу одной из сторон. Оно оказывается лучшим в сравнении с продолжением подчинению «левой пятке высокореповых юзеров». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных пока никаких аргументов в сторону расширения онтопика, кроме "такие вопросы принесут траффик" не прозвучало :( Предлагаете волевым решением взять и запретить?

Comment: @СашаЧерных У нас есть администрация, и она всё решила. Нюанс в том, что эта же администрация ни имеет возможности следить за идеальным соблюдением решения, ни имеет нормальных средств воздействия.

Comment: @PashaPash: Расширение круга вопросов выгодно 1) Владельцам сайта. Вопросы вида _Как поставить мелодию на iPhone?_ соберут большое количество просмотров → Увеличивается доход с рекламы; 2) Самим спрашивающим, т.к. проекты Stack Exchange отличаются высоким качеством ответов. Лучше спрашивать здесь, а не отдельном сообществе, ибо «Например, для участников, которые хотят получить быстрый ответ, существует лишь одно верное сообщество – то, в котором больше участников.»// А почему программисты не игнорируют вопросы тематик Super User, отвечая, собственно, по меткам, на которые подписаны? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных тогда я не вижу причин ограничиваться околокомпьютерной тематикой. otvet.mail.ru, например, не ограничивается, и, наверняка, гребет деньги лопатой :)

Comment: @PashaPash, >Предлагаете волевым решением взять и запретить? — Я не знаю всей предыстории вопроса и не могу с уверенностью заявить, на каком этапе находится механизм поиска консенсуса. Скажу в общих чертах, что самое время принимать волевые решения приходит когда: 1) Новых аргументов не приводится, старые повторяются, — что обычно сопровождается 2) Разрастанием неконструктивных методов ведения дискуссии, будь то переходы на личности, взаимные оскорбления и т. п. Спасибо.

Comment: @PashaPash, мне импонирует идея суперфорума обо всём и вся — проблема в нахождении профессионалов по каждой тематике:  компьютерный Stack Overflow формировался далеко не 1 день, а требуется подобный уровень по всем отраслям знаний. В Ответах@Mail.Ru довольно низок шанс узнать больше, чем смог нагуглить, и пользователи перешли бы на такой форум за качеством. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных SO-не форум. Будь SO форумом, одним из многих - он бы не взлетел. А формат вопросов/ответов или накладывает определенные ограничения на тематику (из очевидных - сама по себе возможность дать объективный ответ), или, если такие ограничения снять - превращает сайт в обычный форум, с неудобным интерфейсом и кучей низкокачественных тем.

Comment: @Discord, на мой взгляд (я статьи писал на данную тему) это общая болезнь организационных форм с самоуправлением. Исполнительная и судебная власть фактически осуществляются не на основе правовых систем, а так, как привыкли поступать участники с опытом и влиянием, порой даже если их действия входят в прямое противоречие с законами, принятыми в данном сообществе. Взывания к закону, правилам обыкновенно не имеют никакого успеха и выглядят чуть ли не смешно. Признаки, конечно, не специфичны именно для самоуправления, но таковые организационные формы отнюдь не служат образцом демократии. Спасибо.

Comment: @PashaPash, прошу прощения, ошибся терминологией. Корректно было сказать не «форум», а «система вопросов и ответов». Её и имел в виду. Спасибо.

Answer (score 12):

Самое главное – тематику сайта выбирает не разработчики, и не модераторы, [тематику выбирает сообщество](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/107/). Приживется та или иная тематика, и если да, то в каком виде, опять же решает сообщество, за счет голосования, закрытия, тревог и обсуждения на Мете.

По опыту Сети Знаний могу сказать, что разделение ХэшКода, как и Stack Overflow на английском, по словам [@Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post), на отдельные сайты не привело ни к чему хорошему.

#### Что мы сделали разделив сообщество?

Мы вынесли все вопросы не касающиеся напрямую языков программирования на отдельные сайты, создав кучу проблем:

- Где задавать вопросы про написание скриптов для настройки системы на bash?
- В каким случаях вопрос про установку и настройку Ubuntu следует адресовать системным администраторам, а в каким продвинутым пользователям? А если надо написать bash–скрипт?
- И т. д.

Проблемы лежат не только в разрезе тематики сообщества, но и в развитии сообществ. Например, для участников, которые хотят получить быстрый ответ, существует лишь одно верное сообщество – то, в котором больше участников.

#### Что следовало сделать?

Оставить один сайт, ограничив список тем.

Именно это и произошло, примерно за год до перехода на платформу Stack Exchange. Мы внесли все темы касающееся системного администрирования в список разрешенных на ХэшКоде (и мигрировали базу РутКода), дополнив их некоторыми темами БитКода, например, вопросами про настройку Unix–подобных систем для домашних нужд (базу данных БитКода не мигрировали).

Уверен, большенство участников сообщества очень творческие люди с огромным кругозором – с ними всегда приятно поддерживать конструктивный диалог, но Stack Overflow, в первую очередь – инструмент разработчика.

Вопросы касающиеся администрирования Unix–подобных ОС встречаются в работе программистов встроенных систем каждую минуту. Относительно вопросов борьбы с вирусами сказать такое сложно.

Comment: Лишь поясню, я не хочу сказать, что вопросы про борьбу с вирусами плохие, не интересные или бесполезны. Они крайне полезны и интересны, но не встречаются в ежедневных рабочих задачах разработчика. Именно поэтому их нет в списке тем Stack Overflow.

Comment: Меня больше смутила фраза про "разделение это плохо". В SE есть куча с айтов вообще не имеющих отношения к IT-тематике, например языковые и сайт юридических вопросов (к слову, такой же русскоязычный пользовался бы бешеной популярностью, при грамотной раскрутке). Плохи ли они? Определённо нет. Если у какого-то сайта сети плохая посещаемость, то это, скорее, вопрос либо слишком узкой специфики (стимул объединять IT-сайты сети), либо плохого маркетинга/администрирования.

Comment: @Risto Имелось в виду именно разделение на [трилогию](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/).

Comment: Интересно то, что если вы пойдёте в обсуждаемый вопрос, то увидите, что его продолжают плюсовать, несмотря на откровенно низкое качество. То есть, часть сообщества активно хочет вопрос спасти.

Comment: @Risto тогда пусть сообщество придет на мету и запостит хотя бы один ответ, обосновывающий включение "как снести расширение" и "угадайте программу по скриншоту в оффтопик". Вы пытаетесь включить в онтопик "непрограммистские вопросы", обосновывая это **одним** (!) вопросом с рейтингом в 6. Хотя вот выше висит ответ с подробным объяснением, почему SU - оффтопик, с рейтингом *10*.

Comment: @Risto То, что вы смогли дать хороший и развернутый ответ на оффтопичный вопрос - не имеет вообще никакого отношения к самому факту оффтопичности. Хотите расширить оффтопик - соберите несколько вопросов, которые вы считаете хорошими, но которые на данный момент - оффтопик. И проведите через голосование на мете.

Comment: @Risto, активное плюсование пресловутого вопроса-ответа это скорее всего протестное голосование (против существующей политики оффтопик), а не попытка спасти конкретный вопрос. (см. ответ Qwertiy тут)

Answer (score 4):

Нет смысла ограничивать тематику, есть смысл ограничивать некачественные вопросы.

Хорошие вопросы про ПО на сайте есть. Не закрытые.

Теперь по поводу опасений про наплыв народа. Во-первых, сейчас этой проблемы нет. Во-вторых, даже если она возникнет, то она вполне решаема при помощи фильтрации по меткам.