# Почему нету сообщества "математика на русском"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Вопросов по математики скопилось очень много, помогает учебник *" Курс математики для технических высших учебных заведений с 1 по 4 часть В. Г. ЗУБКОВ, В. А. ЛЯХОВСКИЙ,А. И. МАРТЫНЕНКО, В. Б. МИНОСЦЕВ"*

**НО ЭТОГО НЕ ХВАТАЕТ**, а спрашивать на английском очень тяжело, есть сайт http://mathhelpplanet.com/ , но я с ним не справился.

Почему нету сообщества " математика на русском" ??

Comment: Есть вот такое наследие молодого ruSO: http://math.hashcode.ru/

Comment: предложите расширение тематике на ru.SO

Comment: отдельный сайт может и не будет достаточно популярным, но в рамках ru.SO метка [математика] может быть популярной: [«Самое главное – тематику сайта выбирает не разработчики, и не модераторы, тематику выбирает сообщество. Приживется та или иная тематика, и если да, то в каком виде, опять же решает сообщество, за счет голосования, закрытия, тревог и обсуждения на Мете.  По опыту Сети Знаний могу сказать, что разделение ХэшКода, как и Stack Overflow на английском, по словам @Tim Post, на отдельные сайты не привело ни к чему хорошему.»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2759/23044)

Comment: в настройках сайта поддержку mathjax включить и вообще замечательно будет. Причём не только для метки [математика]. Многие объяснения от приличной типографии только выиграют. И у нас нет проблемы с производительностью как на английском SO.

Comment: вот пример расширения тематики, который жил на отдельном английском  сайте https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/23044

Comment: Если вам "шашечки" необязательно, то "ехать" можно на форумах, например, dxdy.ru.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Популярность.
Если три с половиной анонимуса хотят сообщество, то не выйдет, ибо нужны определённые показатели (например 100 вопросов в день, на https://area51.stackexchange.com/ подробнее).
Но [можно предложить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) такое сообщество. Если поддержат достаточно много, то может и создадут бету.

Comment: выглядит как не самый простой способ,  мой английский не очень хорош, могли бы вы за меня пройти этот путь ??

Comment: :D Со словариком или гугл-переводчиком можно и самому. Тем более мне не верится что эта затея удатся, уж слишком у них требования велики.

Comment: Предложения на area51 по не-англоязычным сайтам временно отклоняются без рассмотрения.

Comment: А ещё меня расистом называют, чойта так? Может от чёрных тоже автодеклайн?

Comment: Вот тут читайте про всех цветов и оттенков: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack

Comment: Моя слегка не понимать - им сложно поддерживать, переводить сайты на других языках и когда-нибудь они сделают доступ другим? А как же сайты вроде нашего - он уже есть и переводилкины есть (в комментариях на этот счёт тоже возмущаются). Выглядит как расистский пост.

Answer (score 10):

### Из-за нехватки русскоязычных управляющих сообществами*.

Помимо [обычных условий Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) для проектов на языках, отличных от английского, [приводятся два дополнительных условия](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/150564):

- на этом языке должен существовать Stack Overflow (это есть)
- нужно рабочее время управляющего сообществом, свободно владеющего этим языком

Вот с последним пунктом и проблема. И компания не готова от него отказаться, т. к. считает себя ответственной за сообщества, которые организует. То есть, с одной стороны, они бы и не прочь их организовать, у них просто нет на это людей. Не участников, а **сотрудников**.

Если не ошибаюсь, сейчас единственным УС в Stack Overflow, свободно владеющим русским языком, является [Николас](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky). А у него и так полно работы в одном только этом сообществе.

---

** community manager'ов, то бишь*

Comment: Типа нет возможности нанять кого-нибудь из активных в сообществе на этом языке?

Comment: @Other этого кого-то нужно ещё найти и договориться с ним о переходе. А уже найти кого-то подходящего -- непростой процесс.

Comment: Не сложнее обычной работы HR.

Comment: @Other сложность их работы не константна, она параметризована вакансией. Если речь о рекрутерах. Т. к. HR это несколько более широкое понятие.

Comment: Да было бы желание отказать, а отмазки найдутся. Впрочем, наоборот это тоже работает.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще, http://math.hashcode.ru/ ещё живой, вроде.

Comment: Первый комментарий под вопросом.

Comment: @alexolut, ага, только я сначала ответ написал, а потом в комметы полез))