# Причина закрытия "Поиск книги, инструмента, библиотеки..."

Tags: поддержка, тематика, причины-закрытия

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) фигурирует причина закрытия:

- Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Вопрос имеет метку [статус-завершено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), хотя причины выше нет в текущем перечне причин закрытия на ru.SO.

С чем это связано? Вопросы по поиску библиотек -- on-topic? Или же подразумевается, что нужно использовать более общую причину:

- **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ**

  Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос старый, причины закрытия меняются.

Изначально переводили причины с SO, а потом постепенно адаптировали под наш формат.

Теперь, что касается конкретно литературы и библиотек.

По литературе было принято компромиссное решение поддерживать эталонные вопросы со списками - [список таких вопросов](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/178988). Все остальные [должны закрываться как их дубликаты](/a/162/178988). Можно [ставить тревогу модератору для перезакрытия как дубликата](/a/1627/178988) вопроса по литературе, если он закрыт с указанием другой причины. Что делать, если эталонного вопроса нет, не ясно. По идее, надо собрать такой ответ, но это может быть затруднительно. Лично я в таких случаях голосую за сохранение вопроса, но большинство поступает иначе.

Вопросы по библиотекам находятся где-то на грани. Их могут закрыть, а могут и не закрыть - как решит сообщество. Единственное, что с ними решено, - это что [ответы на них со ссылками на библиотеки должны рассматриваться как корректные](/q/1638/178988), а не как ответы-ссылки. Либо с ними всё хорошо, либо они сгинут вместе с вопросом.

Вопросы по инструментам разработчика являются тематическими по другому пункту справки. Но если речь идёт именно о списках, то, формально, было принято решение хранить их [в описаниях меток](/a/1190/178988), но не похоже, чтобы его кто-то придерживался. Насколько я помню, к единственному вопросу про список плагинов отнеслись положительно, так же, как к спискам литературы.

Comment: А что насчет инструментов и руководств так же указанных в причине закрытия? Что касается библиотек, было ли где-то обсуждение "он-топичности" таких вопросов?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, дополнил ответ, в том числе привёл ссылки.