# Тревога - "не по теме" - можно ли просить посоветовать ПО/библиотеку и т. п.?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, тревоги

На "основном" SO в списке вариантов закрытия в разделе off-topic есть пункт о том, что не допускаются вопросы типа "посоветуйте туториал, библиотеку, программу и т. д.". Здесь, на русском SO, такого пункта в списке нет. Это намеренно сделано, как я понимаю? И как реагировать на подобные вопросы? Я сейчас просматривал список проверок "Первые сообщения", там попался вопрос, что-то вроде "посоветуйте библиотеку, с помощью которой можно на Java парсить json". Своего кода участник не привел, и какой-то конкретной проблемы в его коде не было.
И, соответственно, получается, что здесь подобные вопросы допустимы?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2613/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопросы по поиску библиотек [разрешены](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2619/178988), однако это не означает, что все они хорошие. Стоит оценивать конкретный вопрос и при необходимости закрывать с подходящей (или кастомной) причиной.

То же самое касается и поиска программ (см. описание метки [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc) и https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Больше информации можно найти поиском по мете: [`is:q поиск библиотек`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA).